# Macros is not availible when using downloaded google sheets file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I have downloaded a google sheets file with a premade macros in it. When I went to Tools to look for the Macros tab, there was none. Anyone know how to find where it would be in this case or how to fix this error?

Comment: Can I ask you about the meanings of `downloaded google sheets file`?

Answer (score -1):

According to the [Google Sheet Macros Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/macros#things_you_cant_do), there are a couple of things you cannot do with them.

> > When I went to Tools to look for the Macros tab, there was none.

In this case you could be facing an issue if you don't have the permissions for the file, you need edit permissions to be able to access the script (how macros are stored). if you downloaded the file and are opening it in another app, it will not work (again, as per the documentation above).

To be able to access the macros you need to be in the original Sheet, with edit permissions to be able to see/modify them. If you're accessing them externally you will need to create them from scratch.